# How to correctly link SFML 3.0.0 for M1 mac and Clion via Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, clion, apple-m1

I'm new to C++ and that's pretty much my first attempt to create a project with Clion, Cmake and SFML on M1 Mac. I downloaded SFML for arm from https://artifacts.sfml-dev.org/by-branch/master/

Added everything that is .framework to ~/Library/Frameworks

Here's my CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(GameVisualizer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR "./SFML/Library/Frameworks/include")
set(SFML_LIBRARY_DIR "./SFML/Library/Frameworks/lib")

link_directories(SFML_LIBRARY_DIR)
include_directories(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR)

find_package(SFML 3.0.0 COMPONENTS system window graphics network audio)

add_executable(GameVisualizer main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(GameVisualizer sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)
```

rest of the files are in SFML/Library/Frameworks/ in project root.

Compiler set to clang++

main is:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow sfmlWin(sf::VideoMode(600, 360), "Hello World SFML Window");
    sf::Font font;
...
```

Compilation output is

```
====================[ Build | GameVisualizer | Debug ]==========================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/parkharo/Programming/Hive/GameVisualizer/cmake-build-debug --target GameVisualizer -j 6
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/GameVisualizer.dir/main.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/GameVisualizer.dir/main.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/clang++  -I/Users/parkharo/Programming/Hive/GameVisualizer/SFML_INCLUDE_DIR -g -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=12.1 -std=gnu++2a -MD -MT CMakeFiles/GameVisualizer.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/GameVisualizer.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/GameVisualizer.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/parkharo/Programming/Hive/GameVisualizer/main.cpp
/Users/parkharo/Programming/Hive/GameVisualizer/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Im quite wonky with C makefiles also, and would appreciate any direct help or useful links to improve my knowledge in the area.

Comment: Use **absolute paths** for include and library directories. You can refer to the current source directory via `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`.

Comment: On an unrelated question, why do you use the highly in-development (and possibly unstable) `master` branch of SFML, rather than the official and stable 2.5 release?

Comment: 1/ add `REQUIRED` in your `find_package()` 2/Imported targets in master branch are not `sfml-graphics` etc anymore, but `SFML::Graphics` etc. 3/ Your `link_directories()` & `include_directories()` are useless.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've somehow been misleaded by a post where support for apple silicone was denied in 2.5.1, but it turned out that it's there and the simplest way is to follow this guide https://dev.to/giovannicodes/sfml-2-5-1-setup-on-macos-with-clion-505m
Thank you for all the answers <3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).